# Telephone number regex with optional "+"

Tags: asp.net, regex

How would I go about building a regex that allows only digits, with no spaces, and an optional "+" at the beginning?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you want to match your regex; phone numbers in different countries are commonly written in different formats with different separating characters and different numbers of digits. eg. +1(123)456-7890 or +12-34-1234-5678 or +55.1234.1234

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
^\+?\d+$
```

`^` anchors it to the start of the string, `$` to the end

`\+?` is the optional +

`\d` is a digit and the following `+` is the quantifier that says at least one (digit).

A useful resource to learn regular expressions is the [tutorial of regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

And Regexr is a very useful resource to test regular expressions, see this regex [here online](http://regexr.com?2v2fl)

Answer (score 1):

This one should work: `^\+?\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

You need to match a +,maybe, followed by digits. The + is a special character, so you need to escape it. To match a telephone number on its own (nothing else in the string) do `^\+?\d+$`, to match it in a larger string omit the ^ and $ for just `\+?\d+`. You can obviously also change `\d+` to `\d{7}` if you know how many digits there should be.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following:

```
(^\+?[0-9]{10,15})$
```

The + in the beginning is optional as indicated above, with added length restrictions (being minimum 10 digits & maximum 15)